# missing folders from " inetpub/wwwroot "

Tags: coldfusion

I am testing a CFMX code by placing it on a remote desktop, and working on it form my local host. There is an existing folder "D:\inetpub\wwwroot\TEST.com" on the remote desktop. Then ,I placed my code in a folder "D:\inetpub\wwwroot\Aug24\TEST.com”. It was working well a few hours prior.

But alas the folder "Aug24\TEST.com" is empty now. I checked the hidden files and recycle bin,...no luck.

Do files in Inetpub dissaPpear often?Is there any fix for this?

I am not sure if any one else might have tampered with the files.I wanna make sure, before asking my Admin.

Kindly help Thanks and regards Vas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, things don't disappear from \InetPub without something having acted on them.  I suspect that someone removed them or maybe something happened in your CF IDE that torched them.  Check with your admin to see if they know of some action, be it manual removal or some automated process that they have monitoring the folder.